# Magento 2: How to fix error `[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: magento2, database, php-7, php-pdo

I install lampp on linux. Then install Magento 2. However, i get some errors when run any command.
[image: some error shows on terminal]

Comment: Make sure you have enough permission to `var` directory especially `cache` directory

Comment: @KeyurShah, I already given permission to the file permission for Magento 2 in each directory/file.

Answer (score 0):

its not bug , Probably It seems you had no access to the database through terminal.

Please check and gives proper access. for more details please check this [thread](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5173)

Comment: ,Thanks for intersting my query but I 'm not getting exactly ur point which are mentioned above.